# Node-telegram-bot-api через proxy на node.js

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, proxy

Добрый день! Как сделать, чтобы телеграм-бот работал через прокси на node.js (библиотека node-telegram-bot-api)? Стандартный пример нормально запускается дома без прокси, на другой машине, где стоит прокси, соответственно, не работает. Нужно, чтобы работал через прокси. Наверняка, есть какие-то настройки. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, нужен пример кода.

Answer (score 0):

с версии 0.25 и выше можно указать следующие параметры:

```
var bot = new TelegramBot(config.botToken, {
    polling: true,
    request: {
        proxy: 'https://11.22.33.44:1010/'
    }
});
```

Из своего опыта замечу, что нужно указывать урл именно с "https" даже если ssl по факту не используется